# No Roles.CreateRole

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement roles on my website, been searching for a while and it seems pretty straight forward using Roles.[...]

Both creating user (using wizard) and login (asp) are working (without roles)
The problem is, I'm lacking that option on vs2013, any idea why?

Here's what I have in my web.config

```
            <authentication mode="Forms">
              <forms name="Login1" loginUrl="~/default.aspx" path="/"
                cookieless="UseCookies" />
            </authentication>

            <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
              <providers>
                ...
              </providers>
            </profile>


            <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
              <providers>
                <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" ... applicationName="/" />
              </providers>
            </membership>    

            <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
              <providers>
                <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
              </providers>
            </roleManager>
```

Comment: Have you referenced `System.Web.Security`?

Comment: I have now, why couldn't I find that anywhere beats me... thank you very much.

Comment: added as answer below :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reference the [System.Web.Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Once that's added in, you should be able to `Roles.AddUserToRole` and so on.